# How to test Phoenix controllers without setting up the actual database?

Tags: testing, controller, mocking, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am testing some controllers in Phoenix and some of the setup is way too complicated to include in test. For example, I need to test the index function:

```
defmodule ApiWeb.StudentController do
use ApiWeb, :controller

alias Api.Students

action_fallback MsnrApiWeb.FallbackController

def index(conn, %{"semester_id" => semester_id}) do
  students = Students.list_students(semester_id)
  render(conn, "index.json", students: students)
end
```

This is the router:

```
resources "/semesters", SemesterController, except: [:new, :edit] do
  ... 
  resources "/students", StudentController, except: [:new, :edit]
```

And the list_students function is not a regular one:

```
def list_students(semester_id) do
  from(ss in StudentSemester,
    join: s in Student,
    on: ss.semester_id == ^semester_id and ss.student_id == s.user_id,
    join: u in assoc(s, :user),
    preload: [student: {s, user: u}],
    select: ss
  )
  |> Repo.all()
end
```

I have already tested the list_students function, with all the needed setup in all the tables (actually inserting in database), but now I want to test just the controller and view. How can I do that without repeating all the setup I already did for the list_students?

Is there a way to mock the function, without changing the original code?

Answer (score 0):

How involved is your test setup? This is a broad question, but there are a few tools/strategies that you can use.

Ideally your setup should be easy to replicate. You could use something like [ex_machina](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_machina/ExMachina.html) to set up factories to make inserting data easy. That way, getting data into your DB would be as simple as:

```rb
# to insert a single student
insert(:student, semester_id: "someId")

# to insert a list of students
insert_list(10, :student, semester_id: "someId")
```

However, if you don't want to insert data into your DB at all and you really want to avoid calling the function altogether, you could use [meck](https://hexdocs.pm/meck/) and add something like this to your test file:

```rb
:meck.new(Api.Students)
:meck.expect(Api.Students, :list_students, fn semester_id -> [some_results] end)
```

You can also accomplish something similar using [Mox](https://hexdocs.pm/mox/Mox.html) with a couple more steps. But these libraries are more commonly used to mock requests to third party services, you really shouldn't have an issue with inserting data into your DB. If your setup is too complex, you can define some helper functions and reuse them.

But either way, after that, you should be able to test your controllers as usual, so something like:

```rb
test "list_students", %{conn: conn} do
  result = get(conn, Routes.semesters_students_path(conn, :index), %{semester_id: some_semester_id})
  assert [] == json_response(conn, 200)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mock the controller function's response, you should use [Mock (hexdoc)](https://hexdocs.pm/mock/Mock.html), you could hardcode a desired response, the docs should help you get started, it should be straightforward to use, and its in Elixir. However, for effective testing, this would not be wise.